# Ideals generated by Polynomials and coprime polynomials (with more progress)

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory, polynomials

a) Let $f(X),g(X)\in K[X]$ be two polynomials and $I=\left<f,g\right>$ be an ideal in $K[X]$ generated by $f$ and $g$. Prove that $I=(\gcd(f,g))$, i.e., $I$ is generated by $\gcd(f,g)$. Then conclude $I=K[X]$ if $f$ and $g$ are coprime polynomials.

b) Let $p_1,p_2,....p_r\in K[X]$ be coprime polynomials. Prove there exists $h_1,....h_r\in K[X]$ such that
$$\sum_{i=0}^rp_ih_i=1$$

EDIT: Something I worked out in the meantime:

PS: The professor said $I=(\gcd(g,f))$ means that $I$ is generated by $\gcd(g,f)$ (here however, I wonder if the statement is correct)

Let. $I=\left<f,g\right>=\{\,h\mid h= f\cdot k_1+g\cdot k_2\,\}$ where $k_1,k_2$ are in $F[X]$ and let $a=\gcd(f,g)$. So we can say any element $s$ in $I$ is some polynomial $p\cdot a$. Now, (here, I'm quite unsure), based on the property of an ideal, the multiplicative product as well as the addition product of the elements in $I$ are also in $I$ and $\gcd(f,g)$ can be divided by both elements. And since $k_1$ and $k_2$ are in $K$, $\gcd(f,g)$ can be divided by some function $k_3$ in $K$ such that $h=a*k_3$. So we conclude. $I$ is generated by $\gcd(g,f)$ and $I=K[X]$.

2nd try:

Let $I=<f,g>$ and $a=gcd(f,g)$. Then any element $s \in I$ can be divided by a, i.e. $s_i=p_i•a$ for some $p_i \in K[x]$. Since a is in I we can say I is generated by gcd(f,g).

Now I have no idea if this is correct, even if it is, I'd be glad if someone could formalise my proof, i know what i wrote isn't formal at all! Thanks

Comment: The $\operatorname{lcm}$ should be $\gcd$.

Comment: yeaeh. right. sorry, i corrected it

Comment: I consider $I=\gcd(f,g)K[X]$ to be (together with $\gcd(f,g)$ is monic) a _defining_ property of $\gcd(f,g)$ (assuming $f,g$ not both zero). I know there are other ways to characterise $\gcd(f,g)$, but it is hard to show these determine a unique polynomial without establishing the property $I=\gcd(f,g)K[X]$ in the process, so it makes sense to use the latter as definition.

Comment: Thou I’m asked to prove that….

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a final version that is accepted by my professor:

We use double inclusion to prove $<f,g>=gcd(f,g)$

Since $K[X]$ is on Euclidean Domain, $f(x),g(x) \in K[x]$ and let $d(x)=gcd(f(x),g(x)$

Then, there exsist $h_1(x),h_2(x)$ \in K[x] such that

$$f(x)h_1(x)+g(x)h_2(x)=d(x)$$ Therefore

$$d(x)\in <f,g>$$

Then let $q(x),p(x) \in K[x]$ such that
$$p(x)f(x)+q(x)g(x)=H(x)$$

Then $$f(x)=N_1(x)d(x), g(x)=N_2(x)d(x)$$

for some $N_1(x),N_2(x) \in K[X]$. Hence

$$p(x)N_1(x)d(x)+q(x)N_2(x)d(x)=H(x) \Rightarrow d(x)[p(x)N_1(x)+q(x)N_2(x)]=H(x)$$

Thus, now we have proved that $d(x)\in <f,g>$ and $d(x)$ can be the basis of any element in the ideal. Hence I is generated by $gcd(f,g)$.